# zend and security

Tags: php, html, security, zend-framework

When inserting something in your database, is zend escaping the input given through an example  like this:

```
$options = array(
    'bla'=>input
);
$this->insert($options);
```

-- I am still checking the length and validity of the content, partially with Zend_Form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zend will not escape the input, it will use prepared statements (which is even better).

That's why you can't use DB expressions directly, you have to use `Zend_Db_Expr` like this:

```
$data = array(
    'created'      => new Zend_Db_Expr('CURDATE()'),
    ...
);
$this->insert($data);
```

Comment: "That's why you can't use DB expressions directly" --- actually even if zend used escaping - we still wouldn't be able to use expressions without wrapping with `Zend_Db_Expr`.